# Why I cannot pass std::make_unique<S> as a function parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, unique-ptr

Can anyone make it clear for me why I can call `std::make_unique<S>` with only one template parameter, i.e. `S`, like this:

```
auto p = std::make_unique<S>(12, 13);
```

But, I cannot pass `std::make_unique<S>` to a function to do that for me, like this:

```
template <typename FuncType, typename ...Args >
void call_method(FuncType f, Args... args)
{
   f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

struct S
{
   S(int x, int y) {}
};

int main()
{
   call_method(std::make_unique<S>, 12, 13); // not working
   // call_method(std::make_unique<S, int , int>, 12, 13); // works fine
   return 0;
}
```

The shown error by the compiler is:

```
Error C2512 'S::S': no appropriate default constructor available.
```

I am working with Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10.

Comment: A solution would be to pass `[](auto &&... args) { return std::make_unique<S>(decltype(args)(args)...); }`.

Comment: As an aside, this: `Args... args` does not enable forwarding.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica It might be a good idea to also state that `Args&& ...args` would enable forwarding

Comment: @Const This is a simple code to show the example. In the real code, I have to reuse an existing method, like `call_method`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature for `std::make_unique` is

```
template<class T, class... Args>
unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&& ...args);
```

If you call `make_unique` directly the compiler is using template argument deduction to deduce what `Args` should be from what you are invoking it with. By passing `std::make_unique<S>` to your function, you are stating that `Args` is an empty parameter pack, and therefore `std::make_unique` is expecting zero parameters and tries to default construct an S. It is the same as calling `std::make_unique<S>();` directly.